# Woocommerce product brand in productbox

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce store and I want to display the product brand in the product box. I have read many topics on stack overflow and tried many suggested solutions as you can see here:

```
echo "<strong>BRAND: ";
/*foreach ( $brands as $key => $brand ) :
    echo $brand->name;
endforeach;
echo "</strong><br/>";*/
$product_id  = get_the_id();
$product     = wc_get_product( $product_id );

$taxonomy    = `product_tag`;
$brand_names = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );

// Get the brand name
$brand_name = reset( $brand_names );

echo $brand_name;
echo "</strong><br/>";
```

In my database in the wp_term_taxonomy table one of my brands get the taxonomy as 'product_tag':
[image]

Comment: What is the simplest version of what you're trying to achieve?  Are you just trying to echo out `product_tag` from the database?  Also, check the docs for how the grave operator is used - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Comment: I want to echo out the product's brand